# why Authenticate method in AccountController does not cause auditlog?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Base on aspnetboilerplate documents

> The Application Service, MVC Controller, Web API and ASP.NET Core methods are automatically audited by default.

but Authenticate method in AccountController dose not cause to audit log?
Abp version is 3.4.0.0

Comment: can you please supply the link to your document ref?

Comment: as I mention my startup template is aspnetboilerplate https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Audit-Logging

Answer (score 0):

Very simple! All user credentials would be logged with a plain text format. And it'd be a very big security issue!

Comment: in Abp version 2.3.0 authenticate method logged in AbpAuditing. for security reason we can add attrib [DisableAudit] to for example input's password property.  Are you saying this behavior is removed in new version?

Comment: @omidtalebi You said ABP v3.4.0 in your question and ABP v2.3.0 here. Do you mean the template version? There is no `Authenticate` method in [`AccountController` v2.3.0](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/v2.3/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs). Or are you on ASP.NET MVC 5? Please state clearly in your question.

Comment: @aaron in Abp  version 2.3.0 authenticate method logged in abpauditlogs but in 3.4.0 it doesn't. Template is MVC+EntityFramework+Angularjs

Comment: @omidtalebi Are you sure it is logged by `Authenticate` method? Show log.

Comment: @aaron yes. I'm  sure. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdex9vspbit0zqv/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: @aaron yes. after update to v3.4.0 audit log of authenticate method not work

Comment: @aaron calling authenticate method  is not logged in AbpAuditLogs (in Abp v3.4.0)

Comment: @omidtalebi Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @aaron I want to calling authenticate method leading to insert new row in AbpAuditLogs (like version 2.3.0)

Comment: @omidtalebi Erm... Add `[Audited]` attribute?